# Limit Output of Function in Rstudio (3.1.1) when Knitting to PDF

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I would like to limit the number of lines that are produced from a function when I knit my markdown document in R. I've looked around quite a lot but can't find a solution.

My code is below, it gives 50+ lines of data when run. My goal is to only have 9 lines of code produced by the sedist function.

````
```{r, results=1:9}
sedist(FILENAME, method="correlation")
```
````

I have tried using `{r, message=1:9}`, `{r, Hide=1:9}`, `{r, height=1:9}`, `{r, results='hide'}` and similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this??

````
```{r R.options=list(max.print=10)}
df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100)
df
```
````

The `R.options` chunk option in `knitr` allows you to set any of R's options locally for that chunk. Look at `?options` for a list of the options you can set